# Is this the correct way to handle error when calling multi dispatch on a screen?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am making multiple dispatch call in the homepage

Its was something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function getStorageData() {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                await dispatch(fetchProductA());
                await dispatch(fetchProductB());
                await dispatch(fetchProductC());
                await dispatch(fetchProductD());
                await dispatch(fetchProductE());
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }
        getStorageData();
    }, []);
```

The problem is that when calling the these api. I got an error when productC.
So I made a dispatch call.

I try throwing an error but that not work because when I throw an error in productC the remaining product D and E will not be called because throw end the dispatch calling

Here is my api call.

```
export const fetchProductC = () => dispatch => {
    return axios
        .get('productsapi/fetchProductC', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_NEW_PRODUCTS,
                payload: res.data[0]
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: EMPTY_NEW_PRODUCTS,
            });
            console.log('fetching new product error');
            //throw err;
        });
};
```

Here is the reducer

```
case FETCH_NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                listC: action.payload,
            };
case EMPTY_NEW_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                listC: [],
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code after ProductC can't run because it is skipped via catch.
You can write your code like below.

```
await dispatch(fetchProductA()).catch(handleErr);
await dispatch(fetchProductB()).catch(handleErr);
await dispatch(fetchProductC()).catch(handleErr);
await dispatch(fetchProductD()).catch(handleErr);
await dispatch(fetchProductE()).catch(handleErr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never await a dispatch in the component. Read tutorials and refactor your data flow: [Redux Async Data Flow](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#redux-async-data-flow), [Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)

Redux recommends you to [use thunk](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#writing-thunks) to do this:

```
// fetchTodoById is the "thunk action creator"
export function fetchTodoById(todoId) {
  // fetchTodoByIdThunk is the "thunk function"
  return async function fetchTodosThunk(dispatch, getState) {
    // dispatch an action to set a loading state
    dispatch(/*...*/)

    const response = await client.get(`/fakeApi/todo/${todoId}`)

    // use your response and set a success state here
    dispatch(todosLoaded(response.todos))
  }
}

// Your component
function TodoComponent({ todoId }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { data, state } = useSelector(/* your selector */)

  const onFetchClicked = () => {
    // Calls the thunk action creator, and passes the thunk function to dispatch
    dispatch(fetchTodoById(todoId))
  }
}
```